# Deleting a DNN user's role

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

Does anyone know if there is any other API method to programmatically delete a user role? `DeleteUserRole` Method (`PortalId`, `UserId`, `RoleId`) seems to be deprecated since 6.2, am using v.7. TIA

Answer (score 1):

I use this (version 7.3.3)

```
DeleteUserRole(UserInfo objUser, RoleInfo role, PortalSettings portalSettings, bool notifyUser);
```

There are three other overloads, all deprecated since 6.2

```
DeleteUserRole(int roleId, UserInfo user, PortalSettings portalSettings, bool notifyUser);

DeleteUserRole(int userId, RoleInfo role, PortalSettings portalSettings, bool notifyUser);

DeleteUserRole(int portalId, int userId, int roleId);
```

Comment: this refers to calling the static class: RoleController.DeleteUserRole(Me.UserInfo, role, PortalSettings, False)